# Creating a Union of two linked lists

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list, adt

I am trying to create a function that unites two linked lists. I have created a function that does exactly what I am trying to do but as an array of sets instead of nodes that I will provide below.

My Restrictions are as follows: I can use contains() and the Node class accessors and mutators, but, other than those, I cannot use any function calls in my definitions in my union function The operations must be coded without calling any other functions to help.

Any guidance or help to get on the right track would be appreciated.

Here is my array set version of the function I am attempting to code as a linked list:

```
    template <class ItemType>
    ArraySet<ItemType> ArraySet <ItemType> ::setUnion(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2)
    {

        ArraySet<ItemType> unionSet;

        for (int i = 0; i < getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {
            unionSet.add(items[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < set2.getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {
            unionSet.add(set2.items[i]);
            if (items[i] == set2.items[i])
                unionSet.remove(set2.items[i]);
        }

   
        return unionSet;
    }
```

Here is my LinkedSet class:

```
#ifndef LINKED_SET_
#define LINKED_SET_

#include "SetInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

namespace cs_set {

    template<class ItemType>
    class LinkedSet : public SetInterface<ItemType>
    {
        private:
            Node<ItemType>* headPtr;
            int itemCount;

            // Returns either a pointer to the node containing a given entry
            // or nullptr if the entry is not in the bag.
            Node<ItemType>* getPointerTo(const ItemType& target) const;
            void clone(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& copyMe);  //Copy function

        public:
            class ItemNotFoundError {};
            class DuplicateItemError {};
            LinkedSet();    //Constructor #Big3
            LinkedSet operator=(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& right);  //Assignment operator
            LinkedSet(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& aSet); //Copy Constructor #Big3
            virtual ~LinkedSet();   //Destructor #Big3
            int getCurrentSize() const;
            bool isEmpty() const;
            void add(const ItemType& newEntry);
            void remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
            void clear();
            bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
            LinkedSet<ItemType> setUnion(const LinkedSet<ItemType>* set2);
            LinkedSet<ItemType> setIntersection(const LinkedSet<ItemType>* set2);
            LinkedSet<ItemType> setDifference(const LinkedSet<ItemType>* set2);
            //int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
            std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
    };
}

#include "LinkedSet.cpp"
#endif
```

LinkedSet Functions:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "LinkedSet.h"
#include <cstddef>

namespace cs_set {

    template<class ItemType>
    LinkedSet<ItemType>::LinkedSet() {
        headPtr = nullptr;
        itemCount = 0;
    }


    template<class ItemType>
    void LinkedSet<ItemType>::clone(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& copyMe) {
        itemCount = copyMe.itemCount;
        Node<ItemType>* origChainPtr = copyMe.headPtr;

        if (origChainPtr == nullptr) {
            headPtr = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            // Copy first node
            headPtr = new Node<ItemType>();
            headPtr->setItem(origChainPtr->getItem());

            // Copy remaining nodes
            Node<ItemType>* newChainPtr = headPtr;
            origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();

            while (origChainPtr != nullptr) {
                // Get next item from original chain
                ItemType nextItem = origChainPtr->getItem();

                // Create a new node containing the next item
                Node<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>(nextItem);

                // Link new node to end of new chain
                newChainPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);

                // Advance pointer to new last node
                newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();

                // Advance original-chain pointer
                origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
            }

            newChainPtr->setNext(nullptr);
        }
    }


    /* BACKUP JUST INCASE I MESS THINGS UP

    template<class ItemType>
    void LinkedSet<ItemType>::clone(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& aSet) {
        itemCount = aSet.itemCount;
        Node<ItemType>* origChainPtr = aSet.headPtr;

        if (origChainPtr == nullptr) {
            headPtr = nullptr;
        } else {
            // Copy first node
            headPtr = new Node<ItemType>();
            headPtr->setItem(origChainPtr->getItem());

            // Copy remaining nodes
            Node<ItemType>* newChainPtr = headPtr;
            origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();

            while (origChainPtr != nullptr) {
                // Get next item from original chain
                ItemType nextItem = origChainPtr->getItem();

                // Create a new node containing the next item
                Node<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>(nextItem);

                // Link new node to end of new chain
                newChainPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);

                // Advance pointer to new last node
                newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();

                // Advance original-chain pointer
                origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
            }

            newChainPtr->setNext(nullptr);
        }
    }

    */



    template<class ItemType>
    LinkedSet<ItemType>::~LinkedSet() {
       clear();
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    bool LinkedSet<ItemType>::isEmpty() const {
        return itemCount == 0;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    int LinkedSet<ItemType>::getCurrentSize() const {
        return itemCount;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    void LinkedSet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry) {
    
        for (Node<ItemType>* nodePtr = headPtr; nodePtr; nodePtr = nodePtr->getNext())
        {
            if (nodePtr->getItem() == newEntry)
                throw DuplicateItemError();
        } 

        Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>();
        nextNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
        nextNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);

        headPtr = nextNodePtr;          // New node is now first node
        itemCount++;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    std::vector<ItemType> LinkedSet<ItemType>::toVector() const {
        std::vector<ItemType> setContents;
        Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
        while ((curPtr != nullptr)) {
            setContents.push_back(curPtr->getItem());
            curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
        }

        return setContents;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    void LinkedSet<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anEntry) {
        Node<ItemType>* entryNodePtr = getPointerTo(anEntry);
        if (entryNodePtr == nullptr) {
            throw ItemNotFoundError();
        } else {
            // replace data of node to delete with data from first node
            entryNodePtr->setItem(headPtr->getItem());

            // Delete first node
            Node<ItemType>* nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
            headPtr = headPtr->getNext();
            delete nodeToDeletePtr;

            itemCount--;
        }
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    void LinkedSet<ItemType>::clear() {
        Node<ItemType>* nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
        while (headPtr != nullptr) {
            headPtr = headPtr->getNext();
            delete nodeToDeletePtr;
            nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
        }

        headPtr = nullptr;
        itemCount = 0;
    }




    /*
    template<class ItemType>
    int LinkedSet<ItemType>::getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const {
        int frequency = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
        while ((curPtr != nullptr) && (counter < itemCount)) {
            if (anEntry == curPtr->getItem()) {
                frequency++;
            }

            counter++;
            curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
        }

        return frequency;
    }

    */



    template<class ItemType>
    bool LinkedSet<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const {
        return (getPointerTo(anEntry) != nullptr);
    }





    // private
    // Returns either a pointer to the node containing a given entry 
    // or nullptr if the entry is not in the bag.

    template<class ItemType>
    Node<ItemType>* LinkedSet<ItemType>::getPointerTo(const ItemType& anEntry) const {
        bool found = false;
        Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;

        while (!found && (curPtr != nullptr)) {
            if (anEntry == curPtr->getItem()) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
            }
        }

        return curPtr;
    }

    template <class ItemType>
    LinkedSet<ItemType>  LinkedSet<ItemType>::operator=(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& right) {
        if (this != &right) {
            clear();
            clone(right);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<class ItemType>
    LinkedSet<ItemType> ::LinkedSet(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& aSet)
    {
        clone(aSet);
    }

    /* This function is responsible for merging two sets together
    to create one big set by using for loops to add the contents
    of the array sets and also detecting / removing duplicates
    @param set2 used to define the set being used

    @return it returns the merged set

    */

    template <class ItemType>
    LinkedSet<ItemType> LinkedSet <ItemType> ::setUnion(const LinkedSet<ItemType>* set2)
    {

    }

    /*
    This function is responsible for detecting if matching
    values of two sets are detected. For example, if one set
    has {1,2,3) and the second has the same then there are
    three elements that intersect.

    @param set2 used to define the set

    @retunr returns the intersected values
    */

    template <class ItemType>
    LinkedSet<ItemType> LinkedSet<ItemType>::setIntersection(const LinkedSet<ItemType> set2)
    {

    }

    /*
    This function is responsible for detecting values that are present
    in the first set and not the second for example, if set one has values
    (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and set2 has values (1,2,3) then the difference is
    the elements 1,2,3

    @param set2 used to define the set

    @return returns the differences aka numbers that do not appear in the second set

    */

    template<class ItemType>
    LinkedSet<ItemType> LinkedSet<ItemType>::setDifference(const LinkedSet<ItemType> set2)
    {

    }

}
```

Node Class:

```
#ifndef NODE_
#define NODE_

namespace cs_set {

    template<class ItemType>
    class Node {
        private:
           ItemType item;
           Node<ItemType>* next;

        public:
           Node(const ItemType& anItem = ItemType(), Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr = nullptr);
           void setItem(const ItemType& anItem);
           void setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
           ItemType getItem() const ;
           Node<ItemType>* getNext() const ;
    };
}

#include "Node.cpp"
#endif
```

Node Class Functions:

```
#include "Node.h"

namespace cs_set {
    template<class ItemType>
    Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem, Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr) {
        item = anItem;
        next = nextNodePtr;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    void Node<ItemType>::setItem(const ItemType& anItem) {
       item = anItem;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    void Node<ItemType>::setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr) {
       next = nextNodePtr;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    ItemType Node<ItemType>::getItem() const {
       return item;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    Node<ItemType>* Node<ItemType>::getNext() const {
       return next;
    }
}
```

SetInterface class:

```
#ifndef SET_INTERFACE
#define SET_INTERFACE

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace cs_set {
    template<class ItemType>
    class SetInterface
    {
    public:
       /** Gets the current number of entries in this bag.
        @return  The integer number of entries currently in the set. */
       virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;

       /** Sees whether this set is empty.
        @return  True if the set is empty, or false if not. */
       virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

       /** Adds a new entry to this set.
        @post  If successful, newEntry is stored in the set and
           the count of items in the set has increased by 1.
        @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry.
        @return  True if addition was successful, or false if not. */
       virtual void add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;

       /** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this set,
           if possible.
        @post  If successful, anEntry has been removed from the set
           and the count of items in the bag has decreased by 1.
        @param anEntry  The entry to be removed.
        @return  True if removal was successful, or false if not. */
       virtual void remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;

       /** Removes all entries from this set.
        @post  set contains no items, and the count of items is 0. */
       virtual void clear() = 0;

       /** Counts the number of times a given entry appears in this set.
        @param anEntry  The entry to be counted.
        @return  The number of times anEntry appears in the set. */
      // virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

       /** Tests whether this set contains a given entry.
        @param anEntry  The entry to locate.
        @return  True if bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise. */
       virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

       /** Empties and then fills a given vector with all entries that
           are in this set.
        @return  A vector containing all the entries in the bag. */
       virtual std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;

       /** Destroys this set and frees its assigned memory. (See C++ Interlude 2.) */
       virtual ~SetInterface() { }
    };
}
#endif
```

Output I am trying to achieve is:

Set 1 contains:
one two three

Set 2 contains:
four five six

The Union of Both sets is:

one two three four five six

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options how to do the unification of two lists.

1. The solution that is easiest to code is to concatenate the two lists and then check for each element if there is another equal element in the list and if it is not the first you remove it.
2. An intermediate solution is to concatenate the lists, sort the combined list and then go through the list and replace consecutive runs of equal elements with one instance of the elements.
3. The computationally least complex solution in general is to transform the two lists to a set using hashing. Then you're done and can return the elements of the set.

I think you are going for number 3. Using std you would do:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::list<T> unify(const std::list<T>& a, const std::list<T>& b) {
  std::unordered_set<T> combined_set;
  combined_set.insert(a.begin(),a.end());
  combined_set.insert(b.begin(),b.end());
  std::list<T> result;
  for (auto& element : combined_set) result.push_back(element);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: By an ArraySet I meant the function I coded above in my question was used to do what I am trying to do with the ListSet instead of an ArraySet. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Debug I mixed up union with imtersection, that's even easier and I'll fix the answer, sorry.